# How to put arduino in sleep mode?

Tags: sleep

I need to put arduino in sleep mode. I did not find the library avr/sleep.h . From where to download it.

Comment: Just use `#include <avr/sleep.h>`.

Comment: Why didn't you find it? Please post your code that proves this point.

Answer (score 3):

`avr/sleep.h` is part of the compiler. You don't need to download it.

There are other libraries that act as a wrapper to it to make life easier:

- https://github.com/lowpowerlab/lowpower
- https://github.com/rocketscream/Low-Power